# What is the fastest way to apply 150M updates on PostgreSQL table

Tags: postgresql

We have a file of 150M lines which updates only one table of postgresql database with such commands:

```
UPDATE "events" SET "value_1" = XX, "value_2" = XX, "value_3" = XX, "value_4" = XX WHERE "events"."id" = SOME_ID;
```

All id's are unique, there's no way to apply that update to several events. Currently such update takes approx few days if we run this with `\i update.sql` in psql.

Is there any faster way to run it?

Comment: Did you try to run that with autocommit _disabled_ as a single transaction?

Comment: How would it affect DB as it has several hundreds ops per second for that table, can we screw up data or lock table for the whole update?

Comment: Do you have an index on "events"."id"?

Comment: yes we have, that's primary key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Simplest: add `set synchronous_commit=off` before `\i update.sql`
- Better:

  - Split the file to parts of like 100000 updates:
    `split -l 100000 -a 6  --additional-suffix=.sql update.sql update-part`
  - Run these updates in parallel, each file in single transaction, for example with:
    `/bin/ls update-part*.sql \
    | xargs --max-procs=8 --replace psql --single-transaction --file={}`