# Fastest way to anonymize and sanitize field in db table?

Tags: postgresql

For research purposes (e.g. outsourcing to 3rd party data scientist community group), I need to export production db, masking certain sensitive fields (e.g. customer name, phone number, address, etc.).

Now, since the production db on this `order_requests` table has around 500 million rows, I'd like to mask field `nickname` to `nickname_transformed`. How do I do it fast?

`order_requests` table structure:

```
┌──────────────────┬─────────────────────────────┬────────────────────┐
│      Column      │            Type             │Modifiers           │
├──────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼────────────────────┤
│ id               │ integer                     │ not null default   │
│                  │        nextval('order_requests_id_seq'::regclass)│
│ vehicle_cd       │ integer                     │                    │
│ nickname         │ character varying(255)      │                    │
│ phone_number     │ character varying(255)      │                    │
│ pickup_time      │ timestamp without time zone │                    │

... 20+ fields more ...

└──────────────────┴─────────────────────────────┴────────────────────┘
Indexes:
    "order_requests_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    ... 15+ indexes more ...
Foreign-key constraints:
    ... 7 foreign keys ...
Referenced by:
    ... 25+ references more ...
```

My current implementation with `dblink` (6 hours to complete, whereas CPU on DB only < 10%; standalone db used only myself):

```
CREATE EXTENSION dblink;
ALTER TABLE
    order_requests ADD nickname_transformed VARCHAR;
ALTER TABLE order_requests DISABLE TRIGGER USER;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_update_in_steps()
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _step int;   -- size of step
   _cur  int;   -- current ID (starting with minimum)
   _max  int;   -- maximum ID
BEGIN
   SELECT INTO _cur, _max  min(id), max(id) FROM order_requests;
                                         -- 100 slices (steps) hard coded
   _step := ((_max - _cur) / 1000) + 1;  -- rounded, possibly a bit too small
                                         -- +1 to avoid endless loop for 0
   PERFORM dblink_connect('postgres://username:password@localhost:5432/dbname');  -- your foreign server as instructed above

   FOR i IN 0..2000 LOOP                 -- 2000 >> 1000 to make sure we exceed _max
      PERFORM dblink_exec(
       $$UPDATE order_requests
         SET    nickname_transformed = md5(nickname)
         WHERE  id >= $$ || _cur || $$
         AND    id <  $$ || _cur + _step || $$
         AND    true$$);  -- avoid empty update
      _cur := _cur + _step;

      EXIT WHEN _cur > _max;            -- stop when done (never loop till 200)
   END LOOP;

   PERFORM dblink_disconnect();
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Some questions in my mind also:

1. Will it faster if I create an another table with only clone `id`, `nickname` fields + empty `nickname_transformed` field, do my operation there, then *copy* back `nickname_transformed`?
2. This [article](http://postgresql.freeideas.cz/parallel-run-of-queries-functions-tasks-using-dblink/) mentioned more complex way to achieve the result. Is there any solid code example for this? Something like how to manage `dblink` connections and link to their respective operations, `notify`, etc.

Have read this:

- [What is the fastest way to apply 150M updates on PostgreSQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38233631/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-apply-150m-updates-on-postgresql-table)
- [How do I do large non-blocking updates in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113277/how-do-i-do-large-non-blocking-updates-in-postgresql)

Pure function / query is preferred since have to redo this job every 1-2 months.

Answer (score 3):

When I need to update all rows in such a large table I use the following procedure:

- drop all indexes on the table, leaving only these required by foreign keys to the table;
- perform the update - as it does not need to update the indexes it's much faster;
- vacuum full the table - to get back the space used up by old row versions;
- recreate all the indexes - this can be done in parallel - I use `xargs -P` for this.

---

`md5(nickname)` does not provide sufficient anonymity - it's trivially easy to restore back the original nicknames with some brute force or rainbow tables search - they don't have enough entropy.

You should rather do `substring(md5(nickname||'some-long-secret-string') for 8)`:

- a secret would not be known by your contractor, so it would remove the ability to brute force all the nicknames;
- a truncated hash would be too short for reliable reverting of nicknames even if your secret would leak out.

Comment: this one covers some essentials but not complete (e.g. having low cpu, enough memory, and single dedicated host to utilise).

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
update order_requests set nickname = id;
```

and forget about `nickname_transformed`?

If you *must* have `nickname_transformed`, that maintains the same obscured value for a given `nickname`, then:

```
create table nickname_hash (
    nickname varchar(255),
    hashed char(32)
);
insert into nickname_hash
select distinct nickname from order_requests;
update nickname_hash set hashed = md5(nickname);
create index idx1 on nickname_hash(nickname, hashed);
update o set
o.nickname_transformed = h.hashed
from order_requests o, nickname_hash h
where o.nickname = h.nickname;
```

Comment: Have tried this one. Thanks for query but still slow.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with realistic data, you can replace the real data with fake data with a script like https://github.com/joke2k/faker/

This one is in Python but similar scripts exists in many languages